# Emberjs pre4 nested route default URI

Tags: ember.js

Can some one explain why nested resources require to list the path hierarchy in the route name instead of just the route?

Eg. resource1 > resource1.resource2

Emberjs seems to be all about reducing the amount of code.  Is there some usecase for resources I don't see which explains why resources should be defined this way.

I couldn't get my example to work in jsfiddle or jsbin so I hosted it here: http://emberjs.mattmazzola.net/

I was basing my solution from the technique described in this similar StackOverflow question is here: [Ember.js pre4 multiple nested routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712608/ember-js-pre4-multiple-nested-routing)

Basically, you notice I have a resource 'animals' with sub resources 'cats' and 'dogs'.  However, if I just name them 'cats' and 'dogs' respectively the router says "route animals.cats' is not found.  Then if I add the 'animals.' prefix to make the nested route 'animals.cats' the url becomes index#/animals/animals.cats which doesn't make sense.  Of course we fix this by overriding the path attribute, but I don't understand why Emberjs doesn't do this by default.  **Am I defining my resources/routes incorrectly and this is a side affect?**

**In other words, I'm currently doing this:**

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('products', function() {
        this.route('desktops');
        this.route('laptops');
    });
    this.resource('animals', function() {
                // the url for this route is bad, but default behavior?
        this.resource('animals.cats', function() {
            this.route('cat', {path: ':cat_id'});
        });
        // Why does this require stating the parent route 'animals' again?
        this.resource('animals.dogs', {path: 'dogs/'}, function() {
            this.route('dog', {path: ':dog_id'});
        });
    });

});
```

**How can I write routes like this:**

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('products', function() {
        this.route('desktops');
        this.route('laptops');
    });
    this.resource('animals', function() {
        this.resource('cats', function() {
            this.route('cat', {path: ':cat_id'});
        });
        this.resource('dogs', function() {
            this.route('dog', {path: ':dog_id'});
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

hmm, i think the second version should work if you have `App.AnimalsIndexRoute`, `App.CatsIndexRoute` and `App.DogsIndexRoute` (and possibly a few other Ember.Routes) defined correctly. could you maybe post the rest of your code here or in a jsfiddle if you still have that problem?